# Install different recovery from CWM?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, twrp

I'm trying to switch from CWM recovery to TWRP, my phone is a LG Optimus 4X HD / LG P880. Using Simple Recovery Switcher, I tried to flash the TWRP image, but when I reboot into recovery, I get into the CWM recovery again. ADB fastboot told me "remote: bootloader is locked" when I tried to flash the recovery. So I figure the easiest way would be to install the recovery with CWM. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a flashable ZIP of CWM, TWRP,  PhilZ, or even stock recovery, you can flash that recovery from any working custom recovery. Recovery runs completely in RAM, so you write a new one from recovery. Verified through personal use on several Nexus,  Moto, and HTC devices.

Comment: From recovery mode, have you tried `adb shell dd if=RECOVERY_IMAGE of=/dev/block/RECOVERY_DEVICE_FILE`?

Comment: @acejavelin: I can only find *.img's of TWRP, is there a way to make a flashable .zip out of that?

Comment: @Firelord: I guess RECOVERY_IMAGE is to be replaced by the image's file name, but what is RECOVERY_DEVICE_FILE?

Comment: You need to replace that with location of block device file. You can use Diskinfo app or the command `adb shell su -c  'ls -l /dev/block/platform/*/by-name'` to know the  block device corresponding to recovery.

Comment: @Firelord: It just gets weirder. I tried that command and get error su: not found. But my phone has been rooted for ages...

Comment: Did you execute that command when device was booted into recovery mode or in Android OS? If recovery mode, remove `su -c` as well as the single quotes from the command.

Comment: @Firelord: This is the output I got: http://pastebin.com/QLDC0BVm. Is /dev/block/mmcbl then the right block device?

Comment: No. And the naming convention of partitions differs from Nexus devices so I can't identify in that output. Would you consider using DiskInfo app now? Make sure you enable expert option in that app's settings.

Comment: @Firelord Ok, I've installed that app. What do I need to look for? There are a lot of partitions there.

Comment: Did you enable the expert option under its settings? What do you see now?

Comment: Just ticking "expert" and not the other options, I see System (APP), Cache (CAC), Data (UDA), DRM, MLT, CAL, SD card and RAM

Comment: @Firelord (sorry, forgot @ in last comment) when ticking "show unmounted partitions" I also get SOS, LNX, MSC, USP, NVA, FOT, UDB, mmcblk0boot1 and mmcblk0boot0

Comment: If I'm to take [this post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=42249869&postcount=13) at face value, `/dev/block/mmcblk0p1` corresponds to recovery partition in your device.

Comment: @Firelord: It worked! Nearly. DD gave me "no such file or directory" like here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1273032, but pushing it do /data/ and dd'ing it from there worked. Thanks!

Comment: Now, how should I proceed here? Should I edit the answer to mark it as accepted afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

To install any custom recovery, you first must unlock the bootloader. There is an [app for that at XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2263627) which, other than the `oem unlock` method from fastboot, will allow you to unlock/relock several times.

Once unlocked, remaining steps are pretty easy:

#### installing CWM

The following works at least for "Open Euro" variants (I cannot tell for others):

1. Download the image from [the CWM page](https://clockworkmod.com/) (they have the *LG Optimus 4X HD* listed there)
2. give it a short name, for example `recovery.img`, and copy it to the root of your sdcard
3. open a terminal app (or run `adb shell` from your computer), and then

   ```
   su
   cat /mnt/sdcard/recovery.img >/dev/block/mmcblk0p1
   sync
   ```
4. power off the device and reboot into recovery to check if you succeeded.

<sup>Source: [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=41207529&postcount=5)</sup>

#### installing TWRP

TWRP images for the P880 you can e.g. [find here](http://techerrata.com/browse/twrp2/p880). For original links and description, please refer to the [TWRP page for the P880](https://twrp.me/lg/lgoptimus4xhd.html). According to the descriptions there:

1. download the image file
2. boot your device into fastboot/bootloader mode
3. run `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` to install the recovery image
4. run `fastboot reboot`
5. while the device reboots, hold <kbd>power</kbd> and <kbd>vol-</kbd> to boot once into recovery (TWRP will then run a patch to prevent your device from reverting to its stock recovery, which according to the details there some P880 do).

#### Also worth knowing

[acejavelin](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/146132/acejavelin) correctly pointed out in a comment on the question:

> If you have a flashable ZIP of CWM, TWRP, PhilZ, or even stock recovery, you can flash that recovery from any working custom recovery. Recovery runs completely in RAM, so you write a new one from recovery. Verified through personal use on several Nexus, Moto, and HTC devices.

I can confirm that with one exception: On most devices you cannot flash a custom recovery using the stock recovery, as the latter usually checks the signature. Exceptions exist, however.

Comment: You misunderstood me, I already have CWM and want do switch to TWRP, but after every try, I come back to the CWM recovery screen.

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood you then. But still: check the last step of above TWRP instructions, maybe that's what's kicking in here somehow?

Comment: @Izzy The bit acejavelin pointed out is correct. Do you plan to add it as an alternative method to install a recovery?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Thanks for pointing out! I didn't notice that. Done. Though it doesn't solve the OPs issue, it's good to have in this context.